# How do I get the latest beta version of Juju?

Tags: juju

The [Getting started](https://github.com/juju/juju#getting-started) for Juju tells you how to install the stable version of Juju using the stable PPA but I want to try the beta version:

https://launchpad.net/juju-core/trunk/2.0-beta4

What is the PPA configuration needed so I can install that version?

Comment: I am not sure if they have a beta version - perhaps the juju development PPA is the one you need?  (see the list of PPAs at https://launchpad.net/~juju )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juju has documentation about [Geting the Latest Juju](https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/reference-releases#get-the-latest-juju) version and provides specific information for installing the [development](https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/reference-releases#development) branch which is currently version 2.0 Beta 4:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/devel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju
juju version
2.0-beta4-trusty-amd64
```